# How do I refer to one of my two computer monitors?

Tags: word-usage

Imagine that, this is my laptop

[image]

This is another computer monitor connected to my laptop. How do I refer to it in everyday English? Would I say "an extra monitor", "my second monitor", "the laptop's second monitor" or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of your laptop that shows the pictures is a screen. The device that you connect to a desktop computer or a laptop is a monitor. The monitor has a screen at the front.  As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laptop%20screen%2C%20laptop%20monitor&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claptop%20screen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claptop%20monitor%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Claptop%20screen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claptop%20monitor%3B%2Cc0) shows, a few people refer to the laptop screen as a laptop monitor. To be completely unambiguous, you could refer to the device that you attach to your laptop as an external monitor.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no one correct, authorised, specific way to refer to a second monitor attached to your computer, so you’d refer to it the way you’d refer to anything where you have two, and you’re referring to the secondary one: my/the other monitor, my/the extra monitor, my/the second monitor, etc.

It’s worth noting that ‘an/a’ probably isn’t the right word in almost any case here. This is because the other monitor is the only one, and it belongs to you, so both ‘the’ and ‘my’ work well, whereas ‘an extra monitor’ implies that it’s not yours and that you don’t use it very often; ‘I’m using an extra monitor’.

Hope that helps!